# Plotting a nested cell as a predefined structure: MATLAB

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, graph, matlab-figure, cells

I have series of nested cells which represent tree structures. An example of one of these cells with its corresponding structure is the image below:

[image]

I need to know what are the possible methods to draw the corresponding structure in Matlab. So far, I have found [**this method here**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.plot.layout.html) that might be the best solution available, but still I am struggling how to implement it. Thanks.

Comment: **Please see also the** [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665684/finding-number-of-all-nested-cells-in-a-complex-cell)

Comment: Does that cell array match that diagram? I can't follow the logic, since in previous questions `{1, 1}` for example would give 2 branches, but there are no nodes with 2 branches in the diagram and 3 such sub-cell arrays

Comment: @Wolfie I have updated the picture to give you better examples. Each diagram (E1, E2, E3, E4) has its own representative cell written below of it in the picture. The previous questions had a slightly different structure.

Comment: So previously, we counted each sub-array as a new node, which contained however many child nodes. This format appears to define the first element of a sub-array as part of the previous layer, then its child nodes are in the same array? This seems like an odd change to make for such a similar situation, the syntax is quite easily confused! Also `E3` has a missing closing brace...

Comment: @Wolfie I added the brace in the new picture. Yes, exactly; `the first element of a sub-array as part of the previous layer, then its child nodes are in the same array `. This structure is not something I have chosen it is the way my data saved before. It is driven by this structure.

Comment: So was the previous parsing wrong or are there 2 formats at work? Are you struggling with the parsing or the plotting? Does the layout of `treeplot` work for your needs or do you specifically want all child nodes of the same "depth" to be displayed at the same y-position, like above? The more descriptive you can be, and the more you show what you've tried / even pseudocode algorithms you want to implement, the better the answers will be.

Comment: @Wolfie The previous parsing for the other questions was totally correct, but here I am looking at a different structure which requires different parsing. Unfortunately, I could not come up with a good idea yet.The main problem is drawing the nodes at same **y-position**. That is where I could not figure it out how to implement. I doubt it if `treeplot()` could do what I need here though.

Comment: It sounds like you might need to tweak the previous function (don't add a new `rnode`, use the new criteria for a parent node), and use it in combination with an adapted `treeplot` function. Usefully, you can use `edit treeplot` and `edit treelayout` in the command window to see how those functions are written and write your own. Don't over-write/change the default functions, save as and make your own!

Comment: @Wolfie Don't you think this solution might be a better idea: [**second diagram in this webpage**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.plot.layout.html) . _Could not figure how to use it out yet!_

Comment: I've never used that function, feel free to give it a go and add further details to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just so this doesn't remain unanswered...

```
myCellArray = {0,0,{1,0,0,{1,0},0,0},{1,0,{1,0},0},{1,1},0,0};
[myTreeArray,myTreeEvals] = getTreeArray(myCellArray);
MYtreeplot(myTreeArray,myTreeEvals)
```

For the fourth example output, you can modify to suit your needs:
[image]

Two functions, slightly adapted from SO answers, shown below.

First based on [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666560/ploting-a-nested-cell-as-a-tree-using-treeplot-matlab/45676012#45676012) by @Wolfie:

```
function [treearray, nodevals]  = getTreeArray(cellarray)
    % initialise the array construction from node 0
    [nodes, ~, nodevals] = treebuilder(cellarray, 1,0); 
    nodevals = decellify(nodevals);
    treearray = nodes-1;
    % recursive tree building function, pass it a cell array and root node
    function [out, node, nodevals] = treebuilder(cellarray, rnode,skipFirst)
        % Set up variables to be populated whilst looping
        out = []; nodevals = [];
        % Start node off at root node
        node = rnode;
        % Loop over cell array elements, either recurse or add node
        num2Loop = 1:numel(cellarray);
        % ADDED, with input to function everywhere used
        if skipFirst
            num2Loop = 2:numel(cellarray);
        end
        %End ADDED
        for ii = num2Loop
            tb = []; node = node + 1;
            if iscell(cellarray{ii})
                [tb, node] = treebuilder(cellarray{ii}, node,1);
            end
            out = [out, rnode, tb];
        end
        nodevals = [nodevals,cellarray];
    end

    function data = decellify(data)
        try
            data = cellfun(@decellify,data,'un',0);
            if any(cellfun(@iscell,data))
                data = [data{:}];
            end
        catch
            % a non-cell node, so simply return node data as-is
        end
    end
end
```

And based on this [SO answer for treeplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857321/matlabs-treeplot-align-by-node-height-from-top):

```
function MYtreeplot(treearray,nodevals)
% At first we need to get the get the x and y coordinates of every node in the original tree plot and find all leaves in it
[x,y] = treelayout(treearray);
leaves = find( y == min(y) );
%ADDED
if nargin < 2
    leaveParents = find( y ~= min(y) );
    leaveChilds = leaves;
else
    leaveParents = find([nodevals{:}]==1);
    leaveChilds = find([nodevals{:}]~=1);
end
%END ADDED
num_layers = 1/min(y)-1;
chains = zeros(num_layers, length(leaves));
% Next, we reconstruct every chain in the tree plot and store it in a matrix (by doing so, we can later change the y position of the nodes)
for l=1:length(leaves)
    index = leaves(l);
    chain = [];
    chain(1) = index;
    parent_index = treearray(index);
    j = 2;
    while (parent_index ~= 0)
        chain(j) = parent_index;
        parent_index = treearray(parent_index);
        j = j+1;
    end
    chains(:,l) = padarray(flip(chain), [0, num_layers-length(chain)], 'post');
end
% Now we compute the new y-coordinates determined by the row index in the matrix and dependent on the number of layers in the tree:
y_new = zeros(size(y));
for i=1:length(treearray)
    [r,c] = find(chains==i, 1);
    y_new(i) = max(y) - (r-1)*1/(num_layers+1);
end
% We can now plot the re-positioned nodes and add the connecting lines:
figure;plot(x(leaveParents), y_new(leaveParents), '.r','MarkerSize',16);
hold on
plot(x(leaveChilds), y_new(leaveChilds), '.k','MarkerSize',16);
for c=1:size(chains, 2)
    line_x = x(chains(chains(:,c)>0, c));
    line_y = y_new(chains(chains(:,c)>0, c));
    line(line_x, line_y);
end
axis([0 1 0 1]);
```

Comment: _Thank you so much. It worked very well. The plotting time is not bad at all. I do appreciate sharing your knowledge._